# Converting OWL/XML to YAML format?

Tags: yaml, owl, ontology, protege

I have multiple ontologies (OWL/XML format) that I need to convert into YAMLs. Is it doable or not really? I found a python based YAML to OWL converter online, but haven't found anything that does the other way around. I also tried Protege, but it doesn't support conversion to YAML formats.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the question is, how would any OWL axiom look like in YAML fortmat?

Comment: Depending on what the YAML output is intended to be, there might be easier formats to use for conversion. OWL/XML is not as complex as RDF/XML, but there might still be better alternatives. E.g., ntriples or Jason format are available in protégé.

Comment: Have any  information new on this issue?